# stream-API: Replace for-each loop (with expensive operation-call inside) with stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm currently trying to improve my Java8 skills and stumbled upon this case.
My aim is to replace the existing loop in method `foo` with some Java8 stream in method `fooStream`.

The problem is, that I'm calling an extremely expensive operation inside the loop and want to exit it when the result of this call meets my expectations. My stream-implementation now always enters the extremely expensive operation one time more (in the map-call) than my old fashioned loop-implementation.

Can my stream-implementation be improved to prevent this extra call?

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<String> someList = Arrays.asList(null, null, "xxx", null, null, "foo");
    foo(someList);
    fooStream(someList);
  }

  public static String foo(final List<String> someList) {
    for (final String foo : someList) {
      final String result = extremelyExpensiveOperation(foo, "loop");
      if (result != null) {
        return result;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  public static String fooStream(final List<String> someList) {
    return someList //
        .stream() //
        .filter(p -> extremelyExpensiveOperation(p, "streamFilter") != null) //
        .map(p -> extremelyExpensiveOperation(p, "streamMap")) //
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

  private static String extremelyExpensiveOperation(final String foo, final String operation) {
    System.out.println("entered extremelyExpensiveOperation: " + operation);
    // do some extremely expensive operation
    // but in our show and tell case just return foo
    return foo;
  }

}
```

Comment: One question: the `!= null` check that are you doing is for excluding the null values into your `someList` , or you need to call `extremelyExpensiveOperation` on null values aswell?

Comment: This `List` (as the whole example) just for show and tell. The `extremelyExpensiveOperation` must always be called.

Comment: Ok, I've removed my answer then... I suppose the old for loop is more efficient anyway for your case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fairly simple:

```
return someList //
            .stream() //
            .map(p -> extremelyExpensiveOperation(p, "streamFilter"))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```